# i want to redirect into Home Controller after successful login request from Account Controller

Tags: javascript, redirect, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is My Login View Code through which i send ajax call to Account controller

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#save').on('click', function () {
                debugger
                var Email = $("#email").val();
                var Password = $("#password").val();

                if ($("#rememberme").is(":checked")) {
                    var Rememeberme = true;
                }
                debugger
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Account/Login',
                    cache: false,
                    data: { EmailId: Email, Password: Password, Rememeberme: Rememeberme },

                    success: function (response)
                    {
                        debugger
                        alert("User Login Successfully");
                         window.location.href = response.Url;
                        //window.location = '/Home/Index';

                    },
                    error: function ()
                    {
                        debugger
                        alert("error unSuccessfully");

                        //<div class="alert alert-success">
                        // <strong>Error!</strong>Invalid USer</div>

                        }


                });

            });
        });
```

i made two controller one for login (AccountController) and other for Admin(HomeController).After login i want to redirect into HomeController and Index action,but it does not work.My code is below.

```
    //Account Controller For Login


     [HttpPost]                
                public ActionResult Login(Login lg, string ReturnUrl = "")
                {
                    string message = "";
                    using (PresidencyDBEntities1 dc = new PresidencyDBEntities1())
                    {

                        var v = db.UserTbls.Where(a => a.EmailID == lg.EmailID).FirstOrDefault();

                        if (v != null)
                        {

                            //if (!v.IsEmailVerified)
                            //{
                            //    ViewBag.Message = "Please verify your email first";
                            //    return View();
                            //}

                            if (string.Compare(Crypto.Hash(lg.Password), v.Password) == 0)
                            {
                                int timeout = lg.RememberMe ? 525600 : 20; // 525600 min = 1 year
                                var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(lg.EmailID, lg.RememberMe, timeout);
                                string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                                var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
                                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout);
                                cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);


                                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
                                {
                                    return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Home");
                                    //return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl ,success = true, message = "Saved Succesfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                                   // return Json(new { success = true, message = "Saved Succesfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                message = "Invalid credential provided";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            message = "Invalid credential provided";
                        }
                    }
                    ViewBag.Message = message;
                    return View();
                }

<!-- end snippet -->
```

After successful login operation, i want to redirect in this controller

```
 [Authorize]
  public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        PresidencyDBEntities1 db = new PresidencyDBEntities1();
        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> genr = db.TypeTbls.Select(n =>
                  new SelectListItem
                  {
                      Value = n.Type_ID.ToString(),
                      Text = n.Name
                  }).ToList();
            ViewBag.SelectItem = genr;
            return View();

        }
```

Comment: can you please add your html file ?

Comment: You are making an ajax call, and ajax calls cannot redirect. You need to return a `JsonResult` containing the url you want to redirect to, and then use `location.href` - but why in the world are you making an ajax call if you want to redirect (the whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page)

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax code looks correct.only i made few change in login post method.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Login(string user, string pass, bool rememberme)
{
    if ()// login success
    {
        status.Success = true;
        status.Message = "Login successful!";
        status.successURL = Url.Action("Index","Home");
    }
    else
    {
        status.Success = false;
        status.Message = "Invalid UserID or Password!";
        status.successURL = "";
    }
    return Json(status);
}
```

Ajax.

```
success: function (response)
{
if(response.Status)
{
    window.location.href = response.successURL;
}
else{
    alert(response.Message);
}
},
error: function ()
{
   debugger
   alert("error unSuccessfully");

                        //<div class="alert alert-success">
                        // <strong>Error!</strong>Invalid USer</div>

}
```